# Validation password and show password are not working with value.match in javascript and password type in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is a password validation form but I got error for `password.value.match` and also `password.type="text"` is not working.
showHide function can only change the icon, not `password.type`! I need to change type to show it when user needs to see the password.
I can not understand why I got an error on console says:

> main.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match'

```js
showHide = () => {
    if ( show_hide.className == "fa fa-eye") {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye-slash";
        password.type = "text";
    }
    else {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye";
        password.type = "password";
    }
};

const password = document.querySelector('.password');


textChange = () => {
    if (password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) != null)
        valid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    if (password.value.match(/[0-9]/) != null)
        valid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.match(/[!@#$%^&*]/) != null)
        valid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.length > 7)
        valid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');  
}

valid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = "1"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`)
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
}

invalid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = ".5"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`);
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: 0; outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.container .password {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 223  , 223);
    transition: .4s;
}

.container .password:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 30px aqua; }

.container p {
    margin: 10px 10px 30px;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .3s;
}

.container p span {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.fa-check { opacity: 0;}

.fa-times { opacity: 1;}

.container p i {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: larger;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    border: 2px solid rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container #show_hide {
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    font-size: 22px;
    transform: translateX(260px) translateY(-34px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Enter your password" oninput="textChange()" required>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" id="show_hide" onclick="showHide()"></i>
        <p id="capital">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Capital letters</span>
        </p>
        <p id="char">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Special characters</span>
        </p>
        <p id="num">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Using numbers</span>
        </p>
        <p id="more8">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>8+ characters</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If I change querySelectorAll to querySelector nothing will happen to fix my main problem! I still have these errors and match is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have inserted your JS file in head, it's running before page load. you need to put a '**defer**' at the end of your opening tag of script like this:

```
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

also, in some JavaScript environments, if you don't check them step by step, JavaScript will consider chained values as undefined by default. so for solving the bug, you [always] need to check all chained values step by step. old school approach before optional chaining operator was like this:

```
// instead of password.value.match(/[A-Z]/)
password && password.value && password.value.match && password.value.match()
```

but after introducing new optional chaining (?.) you can simply check it like this:

```
// instead of password.value.match(/[A-Z]/)
password?.value?.match?.()

// but since match is a native method,
// (exists in the prototypal object of value)
// you can also write it like this: 
password?.value?.match()
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Hopefully, this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

use `[0]` index to get the first input that found in the document (`querySelectorAll` return multi items and not only one)

Or change the select to be more specific like `getElementById` or `querySelector` (not `All`)

```js
showHide = () => {
    if ( show_hide.className == "fa fa-eye") {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye-slash";
        password.type = "text";
    }
    else {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye";
        password.type = "password";
    }
};

const password = document.querySelectorAll('.password')[0];


textChange = () => {
    if (password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) != null)
        valid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    if (password.value.match(/[0-9]/) != null)
        valid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.match(/[!@#$%^&*]/) != null)
        valid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.length > 7)
        valid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');  
}

valid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = "1"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`)
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
}

invalid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = ".5"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`);
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: 0; outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.container .password {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 223  , 223);
    transition: .4s;
}

.container .password:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 30px aqua; }

.container p {
    margin: 10px 10px 30px;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .3s;
}

.container p span {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.fa-check { opacity: 0;}

.fa-times { opacity: 1;}

.container p i {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: larger;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    border: 2px solid rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container #show_hide {
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    font-size: 22px;
    transform: translateX(260px) translateY(-34px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Enter your password" oninput="textChange()" required>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" id="show_hide" onclick="showHide()"></i>
        <p id="capital">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Capital letters</span>
        </p>
        <p id="char">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Special characters</span>
        </p>
        <p id="num">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>Using numbers</span>
        </p>
        <p id="more8">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
            <span>8+ characters</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Or use `document.querySelector()` for the case that only one passwort field is used.

Comment: It works here with your answer but not in VScode! Can you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```js
const password = document.querySelectorAll('.password');
```

To:

```js
const password = document.querySelector('.password');
```

The reason `password.value.match` was not working was because `document.querySelectorAll` returns an array of DOM nodes whereas you only want a single one, which is why changing it to `document.querySelector` fixes the `match` issue.

Also, I noticed you had a hidden `\b` character at the end of this generated selector which was breaking it. Removing the character fixes the issue:

```js
// change this
let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}\b`);
// to this
let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
```

And then everything should work as expected:

```js
showHide = () => {
    if ( show_hide.className == "fa fa-eye") {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye-slash";
        password.type = "text";
    }
    else {
        show_hide.className = "fa fa-eye";
        password.type = "password";
    }
};

const password = document.querySelector('.password');

textChange = () => {
    if (password.value.match(/[A-Z]/) != null)
        valid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('capital', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    if (password.value.match(/[0-9]/) != null)
        valid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('num', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.match(/[!@#$%^&*]/) != null)
        valid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('char', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');

    if (password.value.length > 7)
        valid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');
    else 
        invalid('more8', 'fa-check', 'fa-times');  
}

valid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = "1"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`)
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
}

invalid = (item, v_icon, inv_icon) => {
    let text = document.querySelector(`#${item}`);
    text.style.opacity = ".5"
    let valid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${v_icon}`);
    valid_icon.style.opacity = '0'
    let invalid_icon = document.querySelector(`#${item} .${inv_icon}`);
    invalid_icon.style.opacity = '1'
}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
    border: 0; outline: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container {
    background: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 380px;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
}

.container .password {
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 50px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: large;
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(20, 223  , 223);
    transition: .4s;
}

.container .password:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 30px aqua; }

.container p {
    margin: 10px 10px 30px;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: .3s;
}

.container p span {
    font-size: 22px;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    margin-left: 45px;
}

.fa-check { opacity: 0;}

.fa-times { opacity: 1;}

.container p i {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: larger;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    border: 2px solid rgb(26, 43, 68);
}

.container #show_hide {
    color: rgb(26, 43, 68);
    font-size: 22px;
    transform: translateX(260px) translateY(-34px);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
    <input type="password" class="password" placeholder="Enter your password" oninput="textChange()" required>
    <i class="fa fa-eye" id="show_hide" onclick="showHide()"></i>
    <p id="capital">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        <span>Capital letters</span>
    </p>
    <p id="char">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        <span>Special characters</span>
    </p>
    <p id="num">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        <span>Using numbers</span>
    </p>
    <p id="more8">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        <span>8+ characters</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
I could not understand this part: And also remove the invalid character at the end of this generated selector.
What do you mean by invalid character? How did you fix match error?

Comment: I did what you said I still have this errors: 10main.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at textChange (main.js:15)
    at HTMLInputElement.oninput (index.html:14)
textChange @ main.js:15
oninput @ index.html:14
main.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of null
    at showHide (main.js:4)
    at HTMLElement.onclick (index.html:15)

Comment: @AminGholami I have answered your original question, if my answer helped you please consider accepting it by clicking on the gray checkmark under the answer score. There's no limit on how many questions you can ask on StackOverflow so if your code is still broken just ask a new follow-up question with the updated code and I can help you there.

Comment: If I change querySelectorAll to querySelector nothing will happen to fix my main problem! I still have these errors and match is not working

Comment: It works here with your answer but not in VScode! Can you please help me? I will select your answer as a best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a class instead of an id?

Maybe I'd try `document.getElementById('')` instead of `document.querySelectorAll('')`.
Also, make sure it retrieves the element AFTER the DOM has been loaded, otherwise it will for sure be empty. So maybe just move you 'const password' assignment into your function.

Then, console.log is your best friend. Try some stuff until you get a value into the console.

Comment: It works here with your answer but not in VScode! Can you please help me?